# Get rows by comparing field dates in mongo db

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to compare two fields of collection mongo itself to get rows, but not able to get it.

```json
    [{
        "date_created" : ISODate("2022-06-24T05:01:15.370+0000"),
        "date_modified" : ISODate("2022-06-29T05:01:15.370+0000"),
    },
    {
        "date_created" : ISODate("2022-06-24T05:01:15.370+0000"),
        "date_modified" : ISODate("2022-06-19T05:01:15.370+0000"),
    },
    {
        "date_created" : ISODate("2022-06-24T05:01:15.370+0000"), 
    }]
```

**Query**

```js
    db.getCollection("collection_name").aggregate([ 
                 {
                    $match: {
                     status: '1',
                          $or: [
                              {
                                  date_modified: { $gt: ISODate('$date_created') } 
                              },
                              { 
                                 date_modified: {
                                     "$exists": false,
                                },
                               },
                           ], 
                    }, 
                },
    ]);
```

**Expected result:**

```json
[{
        "date_created" : ISODate("2022-06-24T05:01:15.370+0000"),
        "date_modified" : ISODate("2022-06-29T05:01:15.370+0000"),
    },{
        "date_created" : ISODate("2022-06-24T05:01:15.370+0000"), 
    }]
```

**Current result:** date_created is not defined

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `$expr` for comparison between fields. Use `$ifNull` to cater your requirement for checking the existence for the `date_created` field.

```js
db.collection.find({
  $expr: {
    $or: [
      {
        $eq: [
          {
            $ifNull: [
              "$date_modified",
              null
            ]
          },
          null
        ]
      },
      {
        $gt: [
          "$date_modified",
          "$date_created"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

Here is the [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/OnIupD46qwp) for your reference.